# Microsoft sublanguage string to locale identifier

Tags: c++, translation

I can't seem to find a way to convert, or find, a local identifier from a sublanguage string. This site shows the mappings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693(v=VS.85).aspx

I want the user to enter a sublanguage string, such as "France (FR)" and to get the local identifier from this, which in this case would be 0x0484. Or the other way around, if a user enters 0x0480 then to return French (FR).

Has anyone encountered this problem before and can point me in the right direction?

Otherwise I'm going to be writing a few mapping statements to hard code it and maintain future releases if anything changes.

BTW, I'm coding in C++ for Windows platform.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting point would be the [LCIDToLocaleName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318698(VS.85).aspx) function and it's opposite - LocaleNameToLCID. Note that these allow converting between LCID and RFC4646 locale name; to get the humanreadable country and language names, use the [GetLocaleInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318103(VS.85).aspx) with the [LOCALE_SENGLISH*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373843(VS.85).aspx) flags. If you need localized names instead of English, use LOCALE_SLOCALIZED* constants instead.

Comment: +1 thanks, I have crossed that one but I'm looking for something a little more human readable. Some of those RFC4646 codes are harder than remembering the 4 char hexidecimal LCIDs, haha.  If I can't find a more suitable answer soon, all mark you correct :)

Comment: I'll give you this one because you started me in the right direction. I posted the bare bones of the code I actually used in by blog > http://corner1001.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/windows-system-languages/ so I hope it can help others

Comment: One problem I've encountered is that 2052 and 1028 both give "zh", but they should give "zh-CN" and "zh-TW".